# Radius of convergence of $\sum a_nz^n$, $a_n$ the number of divisors of $n^{50}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

I have to find the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum a_n z^n$ where $ a_n =$ number of divisors of $n^{50}$.

Options available are:

1. $1$
2. $50$
3. $\frac{1}{50}$
4. $0$

Please suggest how to proceed.

Using the fact that $ d(n)\leq n$, we have $d(n^{50})\leq n^{50}$.

Using the First Comparison Test, the series on the right converges if $\mid{z}\mid< 1$ and however does not converge if $\mid{z}\mid\geq 1$ and hence so does the series on the left. 
Radius of Convergence is 1.

[Now for $a_n =n$, then $ R = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac {a_n}{a_{n+1}} =1. $

So,the series on the right converges for $\mid z \mid<1$]

Now if $ z=1$, then the series $\sum a_n z^n$ takes the form $\sum d(n^{50})$ and since

$ d(n^{50})\geq 1 $, by evoking the comparison test again, the series diverges for $z=1$.

Comment: Please tell us your thoughts on the problem.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Please see my working above. I generally write out my working but here as you can see ...I am totally stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Use the standard inequality $d(n) \leq n$ to [compare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_test) the coefficients of this series with another one.  Obtain a lower bound on the radius of convergence.

Hint 2: Once you have found a lower bound on the radius of convergence, test the convergence at a point on the boundary to show that the bound you found above actually is the exact radius of convergence.

(Here $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By d(n), you mean the number of divisors of n which shall always be less than or equal to n.

Comment: @preeti, yes, $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.  Let me know how far you can get with the hint, and if you need another.

Comment: Please see if it is correct.

Comment: @preeti yes, you are almost there.  But, the comparison test does not give you the exact radius of convergence, only a lower bound.  For example, $1/n! \leq 1$ for all $n$, but $\sum z^n$ converges only for $|z| < 1$ and $\sum z^n/n!$ converges everywhere.  So, if $R$ is the radius of convergence of your series, you have shown that $R \geq 1$.  To show $R = 1$, you now have to show that the series diverges somewhere on the circle $|z| = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the help.Plz suggest if it is OK now.

Comment: @preeti, you have to show that the series $\sum a_n z^n$ diverges for $z=1$.  What do you mean by "the series on the right hand side takes the form $1+1+1+\cdots$"?

Comment: @preeti, let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3481/discussion-between-antonio-vargas-and-preeti)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so from what you did it seems clear that as $\,n\to\infty\,$, the number of divisors of $\,n\,$ , and thus also of $\,n^{50}\,$ , is not bounded, so...?